# Finding power absorbed by a voltage source

Tags: power, circuit-analysis

I would like to find the power absorbed by the voltage source B.
I know that \$P=VI=RI^2=(0.5\Omega)\left( \frac{4-E}{1\Omega + 0.5\Omega}\right)^2\$.

What is the "right way" to find it?

[image]

**Edit:** Basically it gives me three options: \$E=1[V], E=0[V], E=-2[V]\$, and I need to find \$E\$ such that B absorbs the maximum power. Textbook's solution is \$E=1[V]\$.

Comment: Other solution????

Comment: What solution does the textbook give?

Comment: Your power equations are incorrect. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elepow.html

Comment: @PeterSmith They are expressed in peak voltage and peak current.

Comment: You should do the superposition theorem, once you have the mid-point voltage you will be able to measure the voltage difference across the resistor 0.5 ohm, then naturally you can measure the power absorbed.

Comment: Ignoring what you say you know, the problem is under-constrained.

Comment: @Kevin if they are peak voltages and currents why have you used a DC voltage symbol i.e. it's got plus and minus on it? And, at what point were you going to reveal that the voltage sources are sine waves? Your title asks to find the power absorbed yet the answers appear to be in volts. Why?

Comment: The power equation you start with is the the power absorbed by the **resistor** 0.5 ohm, not by the voltage source

Comment: @Andyaka You're right, I've just realized my mistake. I've updated the problem accordingly. The voltage is in DC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The power equation you start with is the the power absorbed by the resistor 0.5 ohm, but you should take into account the power absorbed by the voltage source as well:

\$P=R\cdot I^2+E\cdot I = 0.5\Omega\left( \frac{4\text{ V}-E}{1\Omega + 0.5\Omega}\right)^2 + E\left( \frac{4\text{ V}-E}{1\Omega + 0.5\Omega}\right) \$

\$ P = \frac{2}{9\text{ }\Omega} \left( 16\text{ V}^2-8E+E^2 \right) +\frac{2}{9\text{ V}\Omega}3 \left( 4E-E^2 \right) =  \frac{2}{9\text{ }\Omega} \left( 16\text{ V}^2+4E-2E^2 \right) \$

\$ P = \frac{4}{9\text{ }\Omega} \left( 8\text{ V}^2+2E-E^2 \right) \$

Note you need to find \$E\$ such that B **absorbs** the maximum power, so P should be positive.

Decent way is to find optimum for E, so \$\frac{dP}{dE}=0\$

$$\frac{dP}{dE} = \left( \frac{4}{9\text{ }\Omega} \right) \frac{d}{dE} \Bigg(8\text{ V}^2+2E-E^2 \Bigg) = \left( \frac{4}{9\text{ }\Omega} \right) \left( 2-2E \right) $$

\$\frac{dP}{dE}=0\$ for \$E=1\$

Comment: The power is \$I^2R+EI\$. Both the ideal voltage source and the 0.5 resistor are recipients of power. Your equation does not have units of power.

Comment: After corrections, the equations are still wrong.

Comment: @Chu ah, I see: I copy/pasted to \$E \cdot I^2\$ instead of \$E \cdot I\$ and continued with that ... will update

Comment: For quadratic equation, there is no need to do derivative to find the min/max.

Comment: @XJ You're right. I mistakingly copied \$E \cdot I^2|$ and ended up with a 3rd order... for a second order, this is overdone, but I kept the approach since it is also valid for higher orders.

Answer (score 2):

IB = (4V-E)/1.5Ω=(8V-2E)/3Ω

VB=E+IB*0.5Ω=E+(4V-E)/3=(2E+4V)/3

PB=IB*VB=(8V-2E)*(2E+4V)/9Ω <=4W

and it gets to the maximun when (8V-2E)=(2E+4V) (according to AM–GM inequality) => E=1V

Or, look (8V-2E)*(2E+4V) as a quadratic function of E and let it equal to zero to get the two roots, 4V and -2V. The mid point of these two roots, 1V, corresponds to the max point.

Comment: I must admit your approach is faster,+1 for that

Comment: @Huisman, Thanks!